# Can I create an Outlook 2010 macro to give a pop-up box?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am trying to set up a macro to give me a pop up box to choose which email account I send an email from. I have actually found macros on here which do this but after several attempts during work time all I get is a button on my toolbar which does nothing!

Could anyone give me a detailed description on what to do?

Here is the macro I attempted -

```
Sub SendfromLE()
Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts
   If oAccount = "LeadEmployerRecruitment" Then
      Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
      oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount
      oMail.Display
   End If
Next
End Sub
```

I'm not sure if I have named the account properly? Does it need to be the full email address or just the name?

Comment: It's been years since I did this stuff, but you can also ask on slipstick - Diane Poremsky, Sue Mosher, and those Outlook/Exchange gurus. http://www.slipstick.com/discuss.htm#.T99kzbVYs8o

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts

Debug.Print oAccount
If oAccount = "Whatever you see in the immediate pane" Then
    Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount
    oMail.Display
End If
Next
```